# Button animation in xml for android

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I am having trouble getting my button animation to run when my activity starts up, I am sorta new here and any suggestion will be grateful. Here is what I have at the beginning of my Activity.....

```
    // this is flag for home key press
public static boolean isHome = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.press);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



    // init data
    init();

    // start player display
    start(10000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    spin++;

    // play background music
    playmp3(R.raw.press);
 }
//HERE IS THE WORKING VERSION THAT WAS CORRECTED BY THE ANSWER BELOW
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

     if(hasFocus) {
     final Button b_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttest);
         b_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
         AnimationDrawable b1Amin = (AnimationDrawable) b_1.getBackground();
     b1Amin.start();
    }
 }
```

and here is my animation.xml in my drawable file

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn2" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn3" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn4" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn5" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn6" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn7" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn8" android:duration="100" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: CODE HAS BEEN UPDATED TO THE WORKING VERSION!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start%28%29) for `AnimationDrawable#start()` explicitly states that it should not be invoked from `onCreate(Bundle)` since the `AnimationDrawable` has not been attached to the window yet. Follow the advice in the docs and invoke `start()` from `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` instead.

Comment: Johlo, Thanks for the answer, could have given a short example but it is the right answer and works great. See corrected code above.